# what would be the impact of adding a lot of positive examples to binary classifier?

Tags: machine-learning

Say I have Binary Classifier trained with equal number of **N positive examples** and **N negative examples**. And now, I try to add another **N positive examples** for training. What would be the effect of this?

What would be the effect of having unproportional training examples with respect to label type.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it would mean that you would bias your classification algorithm towards the positive examples. For optimal results, it is therefore important that your training datasets have the same proportion of positive/negative samples than your validation data set (and the data set that you will you in production later on).

The details  might however dependent on the type of the algorithm that you are using and if the added positive samples are independent of the already present positive samples.